# iOS PDFKit memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

I bumped into a problem when memory is loading very heavy when I'm opening PDF and closing it frequently it loads memory. I checked Profiler and figure out that 
`PDFKit -[PDFTilePool _createTileSurfaceForRequest:]`

is not disposing at all.

Here is my code:

```
func configure(with url: URL, delegate: PDFCollectionViewCellDelegate?) {
        self.configure(baseDelegate: delegate)
        self.delegate = delegate
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url)
        pdfView.maxScaleFactor = 6
        pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
        resetZoomAndScrollToFirstPage()
    }
```

Maybe somebody know what is that and how to handle this?[image]

Comment: It woul dhelp if you show your code for how you are loading/using the PDFView

Comment: What's going on on line 2 of your function?  You're calling self.configure(with..) inside of configure(baseDelegate) and then setting a delegate?  Are you setting another delegate in self.configure(baseDelegate)?

Comment: This doesn't show how you are loading/using the PDFView, just how you are configuring it. More worryingly you seem to have an infinite loop in the first line of the function as it just calls itself passing in itself as a parameter.  I'm actually surprised it doesn't just livelock and crash.

Comment: @flanker, its just a delegation to recognise taps on collection view cell

Comment: @RuslanPitula my mistake - misread the method signature trying to view it on my phone.  It's not calling itself at all :-).  It would still help determine the problem if you showed how you were creating and loading the view and where the delegate is bothbeing created/used as that's more likely responsible for any memory leak.

Comment: Try to use `@autoreleasepool`

Answer (score -1):

I think that problem is bug of iOS 13.0. Check it in iOS 12 & iOS 13.3

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. If you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).